# Android Espresso 2.0 stuck on clicking gridview item

Tags: android, gridview, android-espresso, staggered-gridview

I want to create Espresso tests for my Android app. I have a `StaggeredGridView` ([StaggeredGridView Github](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) ) with lots of grid items (~1000) made of custom models (`Recipe.class`)

```
<com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mainPageGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="main_grid"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:column_count="2"
        app:item_margin="8dp">

    </com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView>
```

The grid items are a simple `LinearLayout` with `Image` and `TextView`.

The problem is when I want to click on an element which is not visible on screen then the Espresso stucks and not scroll to it to perfom an action.

I've tried the following (if I change the position to 1, then it works fine):

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.mainPageGridView))
            .atPosition(5)
            .perform(click());
```

And tried this:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.mainPageGridView))
            .atPosition(5)
            .perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

Is it a bug, or am I missing some params?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/

Comment: Did you solved it???

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

`onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.main_drawerGridView)).atPosition(0).perform(click());`